# TCP > COM1 for receiving messages and displaying on POS display pole

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, port, serial-port

I currently have a Java Applet running on my web page that communicates to a display pole via COM1. However since the Java update I can no longer run self-signed Java Applets and I figure it would just be easier to send an AJAX request back to the server and have the server send a response to a TCP port on the computer...the computer would need a TCP > COM virtual adapter. How do I install a virtual adapter to go from a TCP port to COM1?

I've looked into [com0com](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://com0com.sourceforge.net/&ei=LzxgUvnvFOaoyAHIhIDICQ&usg=AFQjCNFWp90Zyb0X23L5EG61fU-obzicrA&bvm=bv.54176721,d.aWc) and that is just confusing as hell to me, and I don't see how to connect any ports to COM1. I've tried [tcp2com](http://tcp2com.sourceforge.net/) but it doesn't seem to install the service in Windows 7 x64. I've tried [com2tcp](http://www.astrogeeks.com/AstroGeeks/COM2TCP/) and the interface seems like it WOULD work (I haven't tested), but I don't want an app running on the desktop...it needs to be a service that runs in the background.

So to summarize how it would work:

- Web page on comp1 sends AJAX request to server
- Server sends text response to comp1 on port 999
- comp1 has virtual COM port listening on port 999, sends data to COM1
- pole displays data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435709/tcp-com1-for-receiving-messages-and-displaying-on-pos-display-pole) I eventually found a TCP > COM program that worked and ended up using another program that made a COM > TCP virtual port. All is working.